# ¿Cómo crear automáticamente un nuevo documento html desde fichero php?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario html (formulario.html) que pide nombre y apellido (por poner de ejemplo), una vez rellenado y enviado, pasa por un fichero php (datos.php) que recoge los datos y los almacena en distintas variables.

El caso es que no sé como hacer, para que una vez recoja los datos, el fichero php, cree un documento html nuevo con esos datos automaticamente.

Comment: A qué te refieres con crear un documento de nuevo? digamos a crear un documento 'resultado.html' cada vez que se envie el formulario?

Comment: Exacto. Cada vez que pase los datos por el formulario y los recoja el  fichero php, que se genere un html con esa informacion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En datos.php tomas las variables del formulario (asumo que es un POST) y creas el archivo con el contenido html que deseas:

```
<?php
$nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
$apellido = strip_tags($_POST['apellido]);

$contenido = "<html><body><h1>Datos</h1><p>$nombre</p><p>$apellido</p></body></html>";

file_put_contents('datos.html', $contenido);
```

Si necesitas crear un archivo distinto cada vez que se envie el formulario, puedes usar el nombre y apellido de la persona y agregarlos al nombre del archivo como tal (aunque sería una buena idea limpiar estos datos de caracteres especiales y similares), o puedes agregar un número verificar que nombres de archivo existen, entre otras opciones.

Comment: Buenas, perdona por tardar en responder. Doy por hecho que file_put_contents, crear el fichero datos.html. Lo cual me vendría perfecto y despues añade el contenido. Gracias por tu respuesta y perdona la tardanza!

Comment: Exactamente, es mucho más sencillo que usar fopen, fwrite, fclose...

Answer (score 4):

Teniendo en cuenta que ya procesas el contenido de las variables del fichero datos.php solo tendría que añadir un par de lineas para crear un fichero y guardar su contenido.

```
<?php
$archivo = fopen("archivo.html", "w") or die("error creando fichero!");
$txt = "Contenido completo en HTML...";
fwrite($archivo, $txt);
fclose($archivo);
?>
```

Comment: Dios, no se me ha ocurrido usar un fopen/fwrite, casi siempre que los he usado es para ficheros .txt. Que fallo mas tonto... gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, Deberias seleccionar esta como respuesta aprobada es mas eficiente que la forma que has puesto como valida, ya que cone sta puedes poner el puntero donde tu quieras @Akarin